# React, render different components and maintain scroll position

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Suppose you have a horizontal flatlist.

When a user clicks a button in an item,  you want to present a view which looks different from the flat-list item you had.

Suppose you implement it like the following

```
     {showDetail ? (
       <DetailView onPress={toggleShowDetail} />
     ) : (
       <FlatList
         data={data}
         renderItem={() => (
           <View>
             <Button onPress={toggleShowDetail} />{' '}
           </View>
         )}
       />
     )}
```

Is the scroll position of flatlist maintained when the flatlist is replaced with `DetailView` and replaced back?

if not, what are the approaches I can take?

I'd like to avoid using modal if possible

- edit,

I'm not sure if setting style `width=0` would maintain the scroll position when set `width=prevSavedWidth` .. but definately can try..

```
import _ from 'lodash'

import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {
  Text,
  Image,
  View,
  NativeModules,
  NativeEventEmitter,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native'

const Qnas = props => {
  const flatlistRef = React.useRef(null)
  const [single, setSingle] = React.useState(false)
  let qnas = [
    {
      title: 'a',
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      title: 'b',
      id: 2,
    },
    {
      title: 'c',
      id: 3,
    },
    {
      title: 'd',
      id: 4,
    },
    {
      title: 'e',
    },
    {
      title: 'f',
    },
    {
      title: 'j',
    },
  ]

  const toggle = () => {
    setSingle(!single)
  }

  const renderItem = ({item: qna, index}) => {
    return (
      <View style={{height: 80, width: 200}}>
        <Text>{qna.title}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggle}>
          <Text>toggle</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }

  const keyExtractor = (item, index) => {
    return `qna-${item.title}-${index}`
  }

  return (
    <View style={{height: 200}}>
      {single ? (
        <View>
          <Text>hello</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggle}>
            <Text>toggle</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          horizontal
          ref={flatlistRef}
          data={qnas}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexDirection: 'column',
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
          }}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  )
}

export default Qnas
```

Answer (score 0):

the questions is not clear, but the scroll position of the page is always maintained , even if you render your components on conditional basis. if you want to make sure that you always scroll to the top of the page when you show the Detail view , you can always do window.scrollTo(0, 0 before showDetail flag as true.

Kindly provide more details for better understanding or share a code pen

Comment: I've added my test code, I haven't created codepen.. you can see scroll position is lost when u toggle from flatlist => single => flatlist

Answer (score 0):

you can have a handleScroll method which gets called on FlatList Scroll and saves the srollPosition in state

````
const handleScroll = event => {
    console.log(event);
    setScrollPosition(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
  };

<FlatList onScroll={handleScroll} />```

and then in your toggle method have a check on if single is true set the scrollPosition of the FlatList using ref

   const toggle = () => {
    if(single){
this.flatlistRef.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: scrollPosition }

setSingle(!single);
}

hope this helps
````